# Unable to name a Mongo database in Docker compose

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong. All I am trying to do is name a Mongo database using docker compose.

I have a docker compose file that looks like this:

```
version: "3"
services:
  mongo-db:
    image: mongo
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
      - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=mydbname
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - mongo-db:/data/db

volumes:
  mongo-db:
```

I run docker `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d --build` and it runs. I then open Robo 3T and connect to my container but every time I do the database is called test and not mydbname. Any ideas? TIA

Answer (score 1):

The environment variables are only used to create a new database if no database already exists. You map a volume to `/data/db` and that volume probably contains an existing database named 'test'.

Find the volume using `docker volume ls`. It's called something like `<directory name>_mongo-db`. Then delete it using `docker volume rm <volume name>`.

Now Docker will create a new, empty volume and Mongo will create a new database when you start the container. And it'll use the values from the environment variables.

Comment: or `docker compose down -v` which deletes all volumes from that Dockerfile. Additionally, it may be in automatically created volume, see line 18 https://hub.docker.com/layers/mongo/library/mongo/4.4.14/images/sha256-5afa88fb1e377a5d4fc928ed0dc04d557a07f4b4e11fa67ec43cea837f1f6eb9?context=explore. Removing the container will make result in not reusing that volume, though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer although I have just followed your steps and the test db still appears :-(

Comment: You probably need to have a script that inserts data into the database. The docs say "MONGO_INIT_DATABASE: This variable allows you to specify the name of a database to be used for creation scripts in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*.js (see Initializing a fresh instance below). MongoDB is fundamentally designed for "create on first use", so if you do not insert data with your JavaScript files, then no database is created."

Comment: Thanks Hans you are right. Thank you for your help it's much appreciated.